# PHP How to total up the sum from each balance in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

code that needs to be totaled up `$v['balance']`

```
foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $k => $v) {
    print array_sum($v['balance']);
}
```

the current code prints the following:

```
0
0.00000938
0.0000007
0.00013408
0.00002358
0.00012234
0.00001106
0.00000159
```

which is correct. I now want to total up all of them. I have tried multiple different ways and they either display the following:

```
foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $k => $v) {
    print $v['balance']+$v['balance']."<br/>";
}
```

print

```
0
1.876E-5
1.42E-6
0.00026816
4.716E-5
0.00025224
2.724E-5
3.18E-6
```

am I doing something incorrectly ?

Comment: Do you want to total up the bottom or what exactly do you want?

Comment: So, what I would do is to create a pivot variable, $totals = 0 before the loop and then $totals = $totals + floatval($v['balance']);

Comment: @julian-schmuckli I would like to total up each `$v['balance']` in the loop for example  `0+0.00000938+0.0000007+0.00013408+0.00002358+0.00012234+0.00001106+0.00000159` = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $k => $v) {
     print array_sum($v['balance']);
     $total = $total + $v['balance'];
}

print $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable from the outer scope of the iteration.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($ss['result']['stats'] as $k => $v) {
    $total += array_sum($v['balance']);
    print array_sum($v['balance']);
}
```